# Are these methods of pub/sub in aioredis equivalent?

Tags: python, redis, python-asyncio

There seem to be two methods to do pub/sub:

1. use channel.wait_message() and channel.get()
2. use Receiver.iter()

The doc says wait_message() is blocking when waiting for new messages. I did some test with a modified aioredis example and they seem both work and not blocking. Are they equivalent?
Do I need to add a small sleep in the reader? If not how does aioredis handle the poll frequency?

```
import asyncio
import aioredis
import random
from itertools import count


async def reader(ch):
    # while await ch.wait_message():
    #     msg = await ch.get_json()
    async for msg in ch.iter(encoding='utf-8'):
        print("Got Message:", msg)
        **# await asyncio.sleep(.1)  # is this necessary?**


async def sender(pub):
    while True:
        pub.publish_json('chan:1', ["Hello", "world"])
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))


async def foo():
    while True:
        print('bar')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())


async def main():
    pub = await aioredis.create_redis(
        'redis://localhost')
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis(
        'redis://localhost')

    ch1, = await sub.subscribe('chan:1')
    tsk = asyncio.ensure_future(reader(ch1))
    tsk1 = asyncio.ensure_future(foo())
    tsk2 = asyncio.ensure_future(sender(pub))

    await foo()
    await sub.unsubscribe('chan:1')
    await tsk
    tsk1.cancel()
    await tsk1
    tsk2.cancel()
    await tsk2
    sub.close()
    pub.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())

    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
```